# Replacement of log4j with slf4j

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I have implemented log4j in my project for logging but as we all know it is slower than slf4j. Thats why I want to upgrade to slf4j. How I can replace log4j with slf4j.
I have created my own framework where I implemented log4j in my whole project. But I want to replace that with slf4j but not able to find a proper method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This answer is bit longer to post it as a comment, so posting it as an
>   answer.

Extending @sazzad answer, `SLF4j` is logging facade and it requires an underlying logging api such as `log4j`,`log4j2`, `logback`, `commons-logging` etc.

So which logging api you are planning to use? 
If you are planning to use log4j itself as an underlying logging api, then you need to use  `slf4j-log4j12` jar in your application. (Make sure not to use both `slf4j-log4j12` and `log4j-over-slf4j` at the same time as it causes an infinite loop) and that's it.

If you are planning to use other logging api such as `logback`, then you need to use `log4j-over-slf4j` jar and respective logging api bridge jar. See [Slf4j Bridging legacy APIs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)